# Creating object with if statement in it

Tags: javascript, object

I want to create a function, which returns an object. Sometimes one parameter of this function is an empty string. If I put an if statement to generate object property only if function parameter is not an empty string: `city.length > 0 ? 'city': city :` it throws an error. Any idea how to properly define an `if` statement inside object?

```
function generateJson(city, state) {
    return {
        city.length > 0 ? 'city': city : ,
        state.length > 0 ? 'state': state : 
    };
}

let city = 'NY';
let state = '';
generateJson(city, state); //output: { 'city': 'NY' }
```

Comment: You cannot do that. Object initializer syntax does not accommodate conditionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will generate a JSON. To convert to JS Object, just use `JSON.parse`.

```js
function generateJson(city, state) {
  return JSON.stringify({
    city: city.length > 0 ? city : undefined,
    state: state.length > 0 ? state: undefined,
  });
}

let city = 'NY';
let state = '';
console.log(generateJson(city, state)); //output: { 'city': 'NY' }
```

Answer (score 1):

One idiom is to use `Object.assign`, taking advantage of the fact that it skips over non-object parameters:

```
function generateJson(city, state) {
    return Object.assign({}, city && {city}, state && {state});
}
```